# read and display the contained an apache poi xls

Tags: android, apache, apache-poi, xls

I would like to display, in a textview, the content of my Excel file.  I read it with this code:

```
private void readExcelFile(Context context, String filename) {

    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        Log.w("FileUtils", "Storage not available or read only");
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Creating Input Stream
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Create a POIFSFileSystem object
        POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

        // Create a workbook using the File System
        HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

        // Get the first sheet from workbook
        HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

        /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
        Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                Log.w("FileUtils", "Cell Value: " + myCell.toString());
                Toast.makeText(context, "cell Value: " + myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.affichage);
               // textViewToChange.setText((CharSequence) myCell);
                Log.d("Debug", String.valueOf(myCell));

            }

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return;
}
```

It's no problem if I have to read the file some other way.
Could you help me?

Comment: You can improve your code by reading and following the advice of http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream and http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator and http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents . Not sure what else you need help with?

Comment: Translated French to English.